# replace a pattern found with a number plus 1 on the same line

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a file where each line contains a keyword (`HELLO`) and one or more numerical fields designated `A1`, `A2`, etc. The value in the numerical field is enclosed in brackets after the field name and is optional; if not present, it defaults to *0*. Each field can contain multiple numbers separated by `:`; I only care about the first. I need to replace the keyword (`HELLO`) with `A1[X-Y+1]. Here is a quick example:

```
case1: my test is (HELLO) with some numbers (A1, A2, A3, A4)
case2: my test is (HELLO) with some numbers (A1[X:Y], A2, A3, A4)
case3: replaceit(something(HELLO)) sometext (single_bit_here, somedatahere[4], something, something,something,something) ;
```

In the first one, the field `A1` isn't given a value, so *0* is assumed. *0+1=1*, so the output is *1*.

In the second case, `A1` has a range *X:Y*, so the result is *X-Y+1*. Let's have *X=10* and *Y=3*. Then "*HELLO*" will become *10-3+1=8*.

Output:

```
case1: my test is (1) with some numbers (A1, A2, A3, A4)
case2: my test is (X-Y+1) with some numbers (A1[X:Y], A2, A3, A4)
case3: replaceit(something(1)) sometext (single_bit_here, somedatahere[4], something, something,something,something) ;
```

The code was modified a bit and it worked for all situations.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[[\\]]"}
{
nFields=split($2,a,":")
if(nFields ==2) n=1+a[1]-a[2]
else n=1
gsub("data_width", n) } 1' <datain.txt
```

the following on question: I need to do the same "inline" replacement for all files in the same dir so I don't need to save back files.  I'd like to use the `perl` script suggested below.

Comment: Your specification says to only consider the first number, but your example output case3 suggests that `A1[x:y]` becomes `x-y+1`.

Comment: Sorry that it should be [x:y] and x>y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test data:

```
$ cat data
case1: my test is (HELLO) with some numbers (A1, A2, A3, A4)
case2: my test is (HELLO) with some numbers (A1[10:3], A2, A3, A4)
case3: replaceit(something(HELLO)) sometext (single_bit_here, somedatahere[4], something, something,something,something) ;
```

The Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my $n = 1;
    $n = 1 + $1 - $2 if (/\([^\,)]*\[(\d+)(?::(\d+))?[^\)]*\)[^\)]*$/);
    s/HELLO/$n/;
    print;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./the-script.pl < data
case1: my test is (1) with some numbers (A1, A2, A3, A4)
case2: my test is (8) with some numbers (A1[10:3], A2, A3, A4)
case3: replaceit(something(1)) sometext (single_bit_here, somedatahere[4], something, something,something,something) ;
```

Comment: I updated the spec so that HELLO need to be replaced by "x-y+1" instead of "x+1".  I also found that your script didn't work properly when there are random space.

Comment: @user3342338 - Updated answer for your updated specs (X-Y+1). Regarding "random space": impossible to fix without exact info. You cannot just introduce "random" without stuff breaking. Your question should reflect all possible cases of "random".

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FS="[[\\]]"}
{
nFields=split($2,a,":")
if(nFields ==2) n=1+a[1]-a[2]
else n=1
gsub("data_width", n) } 1' <datain.txt
this worked ok.  you can modify the perl script.

Comment: @user3342338 - "modify the perl script"?